# If Statement (PHP)

Tags: php, if-statement

I need If Statement (php) to :

```
if (Modem = ModemNotReceived) and (CheckModem = Done) 

    Total + 50

And

    if (Modem = ModemReceived) and (CheckModem = Done)

    Total - 50
```

How i can do that in one if statement?

My Table :

```
| ID |       Modem          | CheckModem | Total
------------------------------------------------
| 1  |   ModemReceived      |    Done    | 120
------------------------------------------------
| 2  |   ModemNotReceived   |    Null    | 90
------------------------------------------------
| 3  |   ModemReceived      |    Null    | 100
```

Comment: Is there any reason why it must be a single if statement and not a multi-line nested if statement?

Comment: Please note that in if condition you are using a assignment operator '=' instead of using an comparision operator '==' , please change that first.

Comment: if((strcmp(Modem,"ModemReceived") == 0) && ((strcmp(CheckModem,"Done") == 0)) { $Total += 50} Else { $Total -= 50}

Comment: Just i need update Total in the table +50 or -50 if Modem changed with CheckModem, and when change ModemNotReceived to ModemReceived update Null to Done and Total - 50

Comment: oh my god. you really need to improve your grammar. please improve the statement of your question. I'm confused of what the question really is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're saying correctly, this code is what you mean:

```
<?php 
if ($Modem == 'ModemNotReceived' && $CheckModem == 'Done') {
    $Total += 50;
} else if ($Modem == 'ModemReceived') && $CheckModem == 'Done' {
    $Total -= 50;
}
?>
```

Comment: Don't you think so it should be like **$Modem == 'ModemNotReceived'**. In your answer you are simply checking a string with another string. You need to check a variable with String value

Comment: Thank you  Kevin Paul Kalis, I am sorry for my English :(